# can't implement android.speech into surfaceview

Tags: android, surfaceview

i'm trying to implement

> android.speech

in a surface view but i can't figure out how can i use

> new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

inside a case

> MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

any help trough this will be appreciated n.n

i already saw this post "[Speech Recognition in Surface View [android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398946/speech-recognition-in-surface-view-android)" but it doesn't completely answer my question u.u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own RecognitionListener implementation.

Here's an example of an Activity that recognizes speech immediately on startup. If you are doing this inside a SurfaceView, you'll need to pass the SurfaceView's context in when you create the speech recognizer.

```
public class BackgroundListenerTest extends Activity implements RecognitionListener {
  /** Text display */
  private TextView blurb;

  /** Parameters for recognition */
  private Intent recognizerIntent;

  /** The ear */
  private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.speech);

    blurb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blurb);

    recognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    recognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);

    recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, "com.example.yourpackage");
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
    recognizer.startListening(recognizerIntent);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    blurb.append("[");
  }

  @Override
  public void onBufferReceived(byte[] arg0) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    blurb.append("] ");
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(int arg0) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onEvent(int arg0,
                      Bundle arg1) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onPartialResults(Bundle arg0) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle arg0) {
    blurb.append("> ");
  }

  @Override
  public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
    ArrayList<String> results = bundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    blurb.append(results.toString() + "\n");
    recognizer.startListening(recognizerIntent);
  }

  @Override
  public void onRmsChanged(float arg0) {
  }
}
```